# How to update 50k rows of a huge table?

Tags: sql, mysql, performance, sql-update

I have a huge table with over 10M rows. I need to update the following rows:

```
select *
from customers_card_psp
where status="not_added"
  and psp_id = 2
order by id
limit 50000
```

Since I have a composite index on `customers_card_psp(psp_id, status)`, query above executes too fast (less than 1 sec). But when I use it in an `UPDATE` query as a sub-query like this:

```
update customers_card_psp
set status = "failure"
where id in (select id
             from customers_card_psp
             where status="not_added"
               and psp_id = 2
             order by id
             limit 50000)
```

it throws:

> #1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

How can I fix the issue?

Comment: 50K rows at once -- Ouch!  Please explain the need for so many at once.  Tips on giant Update:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can join the table

```
update customers_card_psp ccp
JOIN (select id
             from customers_card_psp
             where status="not_added"
               and psp_id = 2
             order by id
             limit 50000) cc
ON ccp.id = cc.id
set status = "failure"
```

Answer (score 0):

check the version with select (VERSION())

and if you can, upgrade to a higher version where limit is supported.